# Using VirtualBox files on new drive or PC

Tags: virtualbox

First time using VirtualBox.  After I install an OS and all the programs and settings I want on this VirtualBox environment, is it possible to save this and then use it on other PC's?

My host PC is using Windows 7.

Another similar question.

My VirtualBox files are currently save under `C:\Users\Jason\VirtualBox VMs`

This folder then has subfolders for each OS that I have installed.  These OS folders contain files like `Linux.vbox`, `Linux.vbox-prev`, `Linux.vdi`, `Logs folder`, and `required folder`

I would like to move all this to a different drive, I'm running low on space on the drive they are currently on, can I simply copy this folder to a new drive or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experiences, I usually have all my VMs on an external hard drive - the key file you really need is the .vdi

What you do is simply move the .vdi over to the desired location and in Virtual Box select the VM from the main menu, right click, properties, and then go to storage. From there you can remove the prior drive location and replace it with the updated spot.

That's how I've done it with CentOS and Ubuntu Server. As far as other OSes, I'm pretty sure if it's supported by virtual box, you'll be good.